# Copy ElasticSearch-Index with Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have an ready-build Apache-Index on one machine, that I would like to *clone* to another machine using logstash. Fairly easy i thought

```
input {
    elasticsearch {
        host => "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
        index => "logs"
    }
}
filter {

}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        cluster => "Loa"
        host => "127.0.0.1"
        protocol => http
        index => "logs"
        index_type => "apache_access"
    }
}
```

that pulls over the docs, but doesn't stop as it uses the default query `"*"` (the original index has ~50.000 docs and I killed the former script, when the new index was over 600.000 docs and rising)

Next I tried to make sure the docs would get updated instead of duplicated, but [this commit](https://github.com/jordansissel/logstash/commit/2ec1188d260a9a81bef4d4c1e8ce497b742fd6b6) hasn't made it yet, so i don't have a primary..

Then I remembered `sincedb` but don't seem to be able to use that in the query (or is that possible)

Any advice? Maybe a complete different approach? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you solve this? Having a similar issue but also the input seems to only run once and doesn't pick up any new entries on the input index.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the elasticsearch input creates a logstash event with the document id ( I assume it will be _id or something similar), try setting the elastic search output the following way:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        cluster => "Loa"
        host => "127.0.0.1"
        protocol => http
        index => "logs"
        index_type => "apache_access"
        document_id => "%{_id}"
     }
 }
```

That way, even if the elasticsearch input, for whatever reason, continues to push the same documents indefinitely, elasticsearch will merely updated the existing documents, instead of creating new documents with new ids.

Once you reach 50,000, you can stop.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. that was the 2nd thing I tried, but unfortunately the `_id` field is not returned by elasticearch-input (that is supposed to be fixed by the commit i linked in my question, but not yet)